# Could a 4th generation neutrino be a viable candidate for dark matter?

Tags: particle-physics, dark-matter, neutrinos

Dark matter does not interact with electromagnetic radiation. Neutrinos also don't interact via electromagnetism, which would make neutrinos a good candidate for dark matter. However because of the extremely low mass of the known three types of neutrinos they can only supply a tiny fraction of the dark matter in the universe (see [the section of the Wikipedia page comparing baryonic and non-baryonic matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Baryonic_vs._nonbaryonic_matter)).

But I have heard there have been speculations in the past, that there could be a fourth type of neutrino, which should be much more heavy that the other three types of neutrinos. Wouldn't such a heavy 4th generation neutrino be the perfect, natural candidate for dark matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Weak physics rates (I think the $Z^0$ lifetime is generally quoted as giving the strongest single constraint) give pretty strong reason to doubt the existence of the fourth generation of 'normal' neutrinos with a mass lower than $\approx 45\,\mathrm{GeV}$, but so-called *"sterile neutrinos"* (which don't couple directly to the weak interaction, but *do* mix with the better know flavors) have been on the radar as candidates for some time.

I haven't checked with a recent review article, but my general feeling is that improved measurements of the mixing parameters have been constraining the possible space for such a mixing term, though it will be essentially impossible to remove all doubt. However the smaller the mixing the harder it is to arrange a large enough mass of such neutrinos in the early universe to explain the observed structure.

These are *not* WIMPs and would not be detected by the current and planned generation of direct observation experiments.

---

Only a day latter I learn of [this recent paper jointly published by Daya Bay and MINOS](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.151801) putting new limits on the mass and mixing angles for oscillation to sterile neutrinos in a minimal 4 flavor model. That said, a few years ago there was a round of interest in 5 flavor models which seems for a time to be more likely (they are, of course, also harder to constrain).

Answer (score -1):

Surprisingly the other neutrino candidate could be an Axion, a very light version (10−6 to 1 eV/c2).  If it is true that Axions were massively produced in the very early universe, the could be a very good candidate for some of the dark matter.

Comment: Huh? This is written as if an axion was a type of neutrino, but they're different things.